# GUI search tool in linux

Tags: regex, linux, search, ubuntu

Coming from windows, there is a fantastic search tool, called find everything, found here: http://www.voidtools.com/
Which can instantly search all files on your hard drives via name. It does not search file contents. It is extremely fast and only takes a minute to scan my almost foll 500gb hard drive. I can also use any regex to search.

I'm wondering if there is an equivalent tool for linux (I am using ubuntu in particular). I am awayre I can use the command `find` in the terminal, but this makes things easier as I can interact with the search results, open the files directly, or get a context menu when right clicking, just as if I was in the explorer.

So is there a close equivalent tool in linux? Or something close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

gnome search tool appears to support regex searches.

http://www.techlw.com/2012/02/install-gnome-search-back-in-ubuntu.html

Comment: This seems to be the best option currently, that I can find. I hate to say it sucks, i figured there would be a more powerful regex based file search tool. alas since im still using this, i am marking as the answer. Though this would be a good excuse to build my node.js chops and try to make something better :)

Answer (score 1):

I use kfind default software for KDE to search files. Or if i need advanced options use recoll.